# How do I use the Harvard citation style?

Tags: bibliographies, harvard-style

I am writing a 6000 word essay on the economic implications of cryptography and was wondering how to use Harvard referencing on latex as support seems somewhat limited.
If the support of Harvard referencing is poor, which referencing system would you advise for the field of computer science?
Any further questions, please leave a comment.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`harvard` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/harvard)?

Comment: The `harvard` package is outdated and has generally been replaced by `natbib` (which is fast being replaced by `biblatex`).

Comment: Here is an excellent reference for this topic from the Imperial College (London) Library Services. [A Harvard style for use with LaTeX
(using natbib) – example ](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/administration-and-support-services/library/public/LaTeX-example-Harvard-apr-2019.pdf)

Answer (score 39):

The Harvard style is basically an author-year style; there are various versions of the general style.  You have two routes that you can use:

**natbib**

The standard way to do bibliographies with author-year citations is to use the `natbib` package and any one of the many bibliography styles available for it.  A basic Harvard style is the `agsm` style.  Other similar styles are `apalike` and `lsalike`.  So you would use in you document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\begin{document}
...
\bibliography{<your-bib-file>}
\end{document}
```

Check the `natbib` documentation for the relevant citation commands.

**biblatex**

You can also use the `biblatex` package which offers extensive author-year type referencing. An alternative to the basic author-year style is the `apa` style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{<your-bib-file.bib>} % note the .bib is required
\begin{document}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Check the `biblatex` documentation for relevant citation commands.

For more information on these two alternatives see:

- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693)

Another Harvard style is the APA style. For more information on this see:

- [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793/2693)

Comment: It's interesting that you say ".bib is required", because it's working perfectly without it for me.