# Problem with bibliography in Harvard style

Tags: bibtex, harvard-style

I am trying to input Harvard style bibliography in my master thesis but I cant do it.  In the pdf file, I see the references but either they do not have the names at all, but they have the `title` of the book the `publisher` and the `year` or they are not placed in the appropriate position or either the `url` that I have inserted is not recognised.
I am using a different file (`Dissertation.bib`):

```
@InBook{Renewal,
ALTauthor = {Breuer, L. and Baum, D.},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {An Introduction to Queueing Theory and Matrix-Analytic Methods},
chapter = {6},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {2005},
OPTkey = {•},
OPTvolume = {•},
OPTnumber = {•},
OPTseries = {•},
OPTtype = {•},
OPTaddress = {•},
OPTedition = {•},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTpages = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
```

> [1] An Introduction to Queueing Theory and Matrix-Analytic Methods,
>   chap- ter 6. Springer, 2005.

In the main program of my dissertation I have:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Dissertation}
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Did you try changing `ALTauthor` into `author`?

Comment: yes,when I change ALTauthor to author it doesn't compile!When I inserted the package that Kurt said I had errors too.\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathtools} this is what I am using

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use BibTeX to cite a web page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page)

Answer (score 6):

Your bibliography file entry should be simply

```
@InBook{Renewal,
  author = {Breuer, L. and Baum, D.},
  title = {An Introduction to Queueing Theory and Matrix-Analytic Methods},
  chapter = 6,
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = 2005,
}
```

All prefixes `ALT` and `OPT` should be removed. They are inserted by `bibtex-mode` in `emacs` and can be removed in one fell swoop (in `emacs`) by `C-c C-c` to 'clean' the bibtex entry.  Also, in your posted code, the fields such as `key` should not have a dot as argument; it is best to remove these lines.

For `@InBook` you should either have an `author` or an `editor` field, but not both; this is  what the `ALT` prefixes are trying to tell you.  A minimal plain file making this work is

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{Renewal}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Dissertation}
\end{document}
```

Now modify this following the instructions of [How do I use the Harvard citation style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39454/15925) to invoke a Harvard like style.

Comment: I don't follow why one can't have both an `author` and an `editor` field in an entry of type `@inbook`. After all, the author of the chapter in question might be different from the editor of the entire book. That said, I think that the OP really ought to be using the entry type `@book` instead of `@inbook` for the entry at hand.

Comment: First of all thanks guys!Now,the problem with the names is corrected,everything looks good,but I can't insert the harvard style,I inserted the package,I changed the style,but I have compile errors,Why?? Last thing, I wanted to insert notes from the internet but the link doesn't appear in the pdf,I have inserted the url package but I can't see the link in the paper,Thank you very very much

Comment: The "ALT" and "OPT" fields do no harm, as BibTeX ignores them.

Comment: @egreg Yes BibTex ignores them, so if they are empty they harmless.  But if you want to provide e.g. the author info, then you must have  `author` and not `ALTauthor`

Comment: @Mico The `plain` style will not print the `editor` field if the `author` field is present.  `@InBook` here is appropriate as it is a single chapter, not the whole book.  `@InCollection` is available for the situation you are thinking of.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Of course you should! The `ALTauthor` field is ignored by all bib styles I know. :)

Comment: @AndrewSwann -- You're correct: I was confusing `@inbook` with `@incollection`.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer but too long for a coment. Just use the following MWE to show us your problem. It includes a `bib` file and loads package `natbib`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}     % creates bib file
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@booklet{mwe,
  author      = {{S}charrer, {M}artin},
  year        = {2012},
  title       = {The mwe-Package},
  edition     = {0.3},
  language    = {english},
  lastchecked = {2012-07-12},
  url         = {http://mirror.ctan.org/pkg/mwe},
  note        = {macros/latex/contrib/mwe}
}
@Book{Renewal,
  author = {Breuer, L. and Baum, D.},
  title = {An Introduction to Queueing Theory and Matrix-Analytic Methods},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = 2005,
}
@booklet{Poisson, 
  author = {Virtamo, J.}, 
  title  = {Queueing Theory / Poisson process}, 
  year   = {2007}, 
  url    = {netlab.tkk.fi/opetus/s38143/luennot/E_poisson.pdf}, 
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}  % \citep{}, \citet{}
\usepackage[%
  hidelinks  % to make links not clickable 
]{hyperref}         % url pretty printing

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

Minimal Working Example MWE.

citations: \cite{Renewal}, \cite{Poisson}, \citep{mwe}, \citet{mwe}, \citep*{mwe}. 

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}  % abbrvnat plainnat
\bibliography{\jobname}       % name of your .bib file here
\end{document}
```

Package `filecontents` is used to keep `bib` file and `tex` code in one MWE.

Comment: Finally I can't compile the latex file when I insert the packages for harvard style,I get errors ,now I have [1] L. Breuer and D. Baum. An Introduction to Queueing Theory and Matrix-
Analytic Methods, chapter 6. Springer, 2005. In harvard its the authors first then the date in brackets,what's going wrong?Thank you very much..

Comment: Everything works fine,thank you very very much,Is there any way to remove the colours and the boxes from my main pdf,because I don't like them

Comment: In fact is there any way not to make clickable the links,and how in the bib file can I leave a line because in this reference @booklet{Poisson,
author = {Virtamo, J.},
title = {Queueing Theory / Poisson process},
year = {2007},
url = {http://www.netlab.tkk.fi/opetus/s38143/luennot/E_poisson.pdf},
}the year and the url are on the same line