# Effects of removing chapter field from bibliographic entry

Tags: bibtex, harvard-style

I have two questions,
I am using Bibtex and Harvard style for my bibliography, everything works really good except from two things,

```
@InBook{Intro2,
author = {Yong, J.},
title = {Recent Developments in Mathematical Finance},
chapter = {19},
publisher = {World Scientific},
year = {2002},
}
```

If for the above example I want to remove the chapter because I have taken other parts from the book, Latex does not let me, I have an error saying that I have to insert chapter.

Secondly,

```
@Article{Ph2,
author = {Fackrell, M.},
title = {Modelling healthcare systems with phase-type distributions},
journal = {Volume 12, Number 1, Pages 11-26},
year = {2009},
}
```

for the above example I am using an article and in my paper I do not have italics for the title of the article but for the journal as shown below:

M. Fackrell. Modelling healthcare systems with phase-type distributions. *Volume 12, Number 1, Pages 11-26, 2009.*

Comment: Which bibbliography style do you use? Depending on the bibliography style, the `chapter` field may be *required* for entries of type `@inbook`, and that's why BibTeX will report an error. If you want to refer to a different chapter of the book, you should consider creating a separate entry, while leaving the entry with key `Intro2` as it is.

Comment: I am using exactly what kurt said me
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66941/problem-with-bibliography-in-harvard-style/66952#comment142574_66952
In this address,his answer!!
thanks

Comment: I've checked @Kurt's answer that you cross-reference. It appears to use the `natbib` citation package rather than the `harvard` package; I thus fail to see its applicability to your new question. Or are you, in fact, using the `natbib` package? If so, please edit your question to incorporate this fact.

Comment: yes, you are correct, I am using natbib package, because I did not know how to use the Harvard package, and it looked ok,but now I have these problems and I do not know how to solve them

Answer (score 1):

(This answer incorporates the OP's comments that the `natbib` package, rather than the `harvard` package, is used. Furthermore, it assumes that a bibliography style such as `plainnat` or `unsrtnat` is used.)

You're dealing with two separate problems. If I understand your first issue correctly, you run into problems if you eliminate the `chapter` field from the entry with key `Intro2`. This is because for entries of type `@inbook` and a bibliography style such as `unsrtnat`, the `chapter` field is *required*; if it's omitted an error message is generated. If you want to refer to the entire book, rather than just to one specific chapter, please consider creating a new entry, of type `@book`, along the following lines:

```
@Book{yong:02,
    author = {Yong, J.},
    title = {Recent Developments in Mathematical Finance},
    publisher = {World Scientific},
    year = {2002},
}
```

You can then cite the entire piece with a command such as `\citet{yong:02}`. If you want to draw attention to a specific chapter -- say, chapter 12 -- in your citation, you could issue the command `\citet[ch.~12]{yong:02}` to do so: this will generate the citation `Yong (2012, ch.~12)`. The `~` (tilde) serves as a "tie" to prevent a line break between "ch." and "12".

The second problem arises because (i) the journal name is currently *not* provided in the entry and (ii) the `journal` field instead contains information that should be provided in `volume`, `number`, and `pages` fields. A corrected entry might look like this:

```
@Article{Ph2,
    author = {Fackrell, M.},
    title = {Modelling healthcare systems with phase-type distributions},
    journal = {Health Care Management Science},
    volume = 12, 
    number = 1, 
    pages = {11-26},
    year = {2009},
}
```

Comment: @Vangelis - I'm glad everything's working for you now. Feel free to "accept" (by clicking on the check-mark symbol) my answer. :-)