# changing u. a. of German to et. al

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker

I am using Texmaker under linux. My citations are like [author,year] which is as I want and I am using `\bibliographystyle{dinat}` and `\usepackage[square]{natbib}`. But I want to change [author u. a., year] to [author et al., year]. The u. a. is the equivalent of et al. in German.
How can I do that? Should I change the style?
I have tried `\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}` but there is no change.

Comment: The `dinat` bibliography style is specifically designed for German, and all of words and abbreviations ('editor', 'and', 'et al.') etc. will be in German. It might be simpler to use a different bibliography style.  Is there a particular reason why you need to use an English `dinat` style?

Comment: I was tolled to use at university. The style should be like [Author, year] and I guess that is the only reason. can I use harvard style?

Comment: I have tried http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39457/75258 as well (the natbib suggestion) but there is no change in that!

Comment: What do you mean, no change? If you change the `bibliographystyle` command, you need to delete your `.aux` files and rerun `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` to see the new style.

Comment: Ok. I tried it as you said, but these styles are not like[author,year]. They put numbers for citation.

Answer (score 7):

Following worked for me with APA style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    bibwarn=true,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    style=apa,
]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
  Sample: \textcite{beck:2001}
\end{document}
```

Bibliography.bib:

```
@misc{beck:2001,
  Author    = {Beck, K. and Beedle, M. and van Bennekum, A. and Cockburn, A. and Cunningham, W. and Fowler, M. and Grenning, J. and Highsmith, J. and Hunt, A. and Jeffries, R. and Kern, J. and Marick, B. and Martin, R.C. and Mellor, S. and Schwaber, K. and Sutherland, J. and Thomas, D.},
  Title     = {Manifesto for Agile Software Development},
  Year      = {2001},
  URL       = {http://www.agilemanifesto.org/},
}
```

Credits go to [this guy](http://golatex.de/biblatex-apa-u-a-in-et-al-umwandeln-t10074.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `astron` style, as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39457/36033), worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simply changing the pushed standard texts defined in dinat.bst will work.

I downloaded the dinat.bst file: https://ctan.org/pkg/dinat

and modified

> FUNCTION {push.ua}        { "u.\,a." }
>
> FUNCTION {push.und}       { "und" }

into

> FUNCTION {push.ua}        { "et \,al." }
>
> FUNCTION {push.und}       { "and" }

Then, put this file in the folder of the .tex file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with similar style, as you are having. The following code worked for me to get 'u.a.' to 'et al.':

```
\usepackage[sort&compress, square]{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}
   \citep{Author.2020}
   \bibliography{bib_file}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change the entry in your .bib file, i. e. put curly brackets:

```
AUTHOR       = "{Beck, K. et al.}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to cleanup all of Latex's auxiliary files and recompile from scratch. I then used

```
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
% ....
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```