# Undefined control sequence \citeasnoun

Tags: natbib, harvard-style

I want to use harvard referencing style. I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\title{test}
\author{ }
\date{February 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

blab \cite{Jensen2007} has done it
\citeasnoun{Jensen2007} blub bla
\citeasnoun{Jensen2007} blub bla blub.


\section{Introduction}
\bibliography{bibliography} 

\end{document}
```

Latex keeps saying ! Undefined control sequence. l.19 \citeasnoun {Jensen2007} blub bla blub.

But I wrote \citeasnoun correctly and followed the instruction on [How do I use the Harvard citation style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39454/how-do-i-use-the-harvard-citation-style) (using natbib). Why do I get this error all the time?

Comment: On the page you linked i cannot find `citeasnoun`. Where is it from?

Comment: The `\citeasnoun` command is from the `harvard` package, which is pretty outdated. The `natbib` equivalent is `\citet`.  The `natbib` documentation is a little confusing in this respect, since the last section describes a bunch of other packages, all of which `natbib` can replace, although with slightly different commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following basic  citation commands are defined in `natbib`:

```
\citet{jon90,jam91} ⇒ Jones et al. (1990); James et al. (1991)
\citep{jon90,jam91} ⇒ (Jones et al., 1990; James et al. 1991)
\citep{jon90,jon91} ⇒ (Jones et al., 1990, 1991)
\citep{jon90a,jon90b} ⇒ (Jones et al., 1990a,b)
```

Additionally there are some extended commands too:

```
\citealt{jon90} ⇒ Jones et al. 1990
\citealt*{jon90} ⇒ Jones, Baker, and Williams 1990
\citealp{jon90} ⇒ Jones et al., 1990
\citealp*{jon90} ⇒ Jones, Baker, and Williams, 1990
\citealp{jon90,jam91} ⇒ Jones et al., 1990; James et al., 1991
\citealp[pg.~32]{jon90}  ⇒ Jones et al., 1990, pg. 32
\citenum{jon90} ⇒ 11
\citetext{priv.\ comm.} ⇒ (priv. comm.)
```

To extract just part of a citation, e.g. the author name or year, you can also use:

```
\citeauthor{jon90} ⇒ Jones et al.
\citeauthor*{jon90} ⇒ Jones, Baker, and Williams
\citeyear{jon90}  ⇒ 1990
\citeyearpar{jon90} ⇒ (1990)
```

There are also uppercase versions of the citation commands for sentence initial citations of names that have a name prefix such as "de" or "von".

The `\citeasnoun` command is from a different package. The `natbib` documentation is a bit confusing in this respect, since the last section describes a bunch of other packages, all of which `natbib` is intended to replace.

Answer (score 2):

Load both the `natbib` and the `har2nat` packages. The latter "translates" macros defined in `harvard.sty` to expressions understood by `natbib`.

For instance, the file `har2nat.sty` contains the instruction

```
\newcommand{\citeasnoun}{\citet}
```

Note that `har2nat` must be loaded *after* `natbib`. In any case, the `harvard` package should *not* be loaded.

Comment: Of course, this is only advisable for existing code. If one is starting from scratch, it makes more sense to use the `natbib` commands directly.

Comment: @AlanMunn - I fully agree. The `har2nat` package is meant to be used with legacy documents that (a) use one of the 7 bibliography styles of the `harvard` package (`agsm` being one of them) and (b) use some of the citation-related macros (such as `\citeasnoun`) of the `harvard` package.